# Multiple NSTimers in spritekit not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

**Aim:**

I have particles falling from the top of the screen and I would like them to increase their speed, as the score reaches a certain value.

**Previous failed attempt:**

I first made those falling particles affected by gravity and tried to increase the value of gravity as the score hit a certain value. However it didn't seem to work so I assume that gravity cannot be changed during the game.

**Current situation:**

After some research, I thought of using two global NSTimers, `slowTimer` and `fastTimer`. `slowTimer` is called in `didMoveToView`. In `touchesBegan`, everytime there is a tap, I call a function, changeSpeed which is this :

```
    func changeSpeed()
        {

            if score >= 2

            {
                slowTimer.invalidate()
                makeWallsDividerT = 300

                fastTimer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.4, target: self, selector: Selector("makeWalls"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }

        }
```

`makeWallsDividerT` is a variable in the `function makeWalls` which is called by the `fastTimer`.

**Problem with current situation :**

When it is game over and everything is reset, I do `fastTimer.invalidate()` and still there seem to be problems as it is not resetting to slowTimer. Also it seems that both timers are on as after reset, the game is much faster than fastTimer.

Any pointers please? Or any other ways of achieving what I am trying to do?
Thanks!!

Comment: How do you create particles ? It is confusing a bit, because particles usually refer to particles emitted by `SKEmitterNode`. By the way, use `SKActions` instead of `NSTimer`... `SKActions` are paired with a game loop.

Comment: I am curious how many times changeSpeed is getting called,  it is possible you have multiple timers being fired, but fastTimer is only retaining your last assigned timer, leaving the others with no way of invalidating.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: when the game starts, I want slowTimer to be called only once till the score gets to 2. Then it will be fastTimer for the rest of the game till it is game over. Then when the game is restarted, it will be slowTimer again till the score is 2 and then fastTimer till game over. The same loop will happen as many times as the game is played. Thanks!!

Comment: You are saying every time touchBegans  is called, you are changing speed,  which is why I asked my question.  If you do not invalidate fastTimer EVERY tap, you will have many timers firing

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ah icc! Thanks for that. Do you have any advise please? What I am trying to do is this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265482/multiple-nstimers-in-spritekit-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment60163969_36265766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rework your code so that you are no longer using NSTimers, you want to do the following:

```
override func didMoveToView(view:SKView)
{
    let spawnWall = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.makeWalls();});
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3),spawnWall])
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence);
    self.runAction(repeatForver, withKey:"makeWalls"); 
}

func changeSpeed()
{
    if score >= 2
    {
        self.removeActionForKey("makeWalls");  
        makeWallsDividerT = 300;
        let spawnWall = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.makeWalls();});
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.4),spawnWall])
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence);
        self.runAction(repeatForver, withKey:"makeWalls"); 

    }
}
```

This will prevent multiple actions being fired.  (In your case, you had multiple timers being fired, and you only stopped the last timer made.)

Comment: you may not want to make makeWallsDividerT global anymore, you can pass it into your makeWalls function

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience Sir. The first block of code runs perfectly fine, just like the NSTimer did. However the second is not being executed at all. Maybe this is because we are not calling changeSpeed() from didMoveToView. So I think when the functions in the class are executed in a chronological order, when it gets to changeSpeed, it checks the score. Since the score is not >=2, that block of code (changeSpeed) is not executed. However I want it to be executed when the score is of that value. Could you help with that please? Thanks!

Comment: Wait what i am confused again

Comment: That is great stuff mate! Calling it in touchesBegan does the trick and works just fine! The only problem now is that when the game is reset, it is calling the makeWalls function every 1.4 seconds by default. It is meant to call it every 3 seconds till the score gets to >=2 and then it should call it every 1.4 seconds. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ok i do not know your logic to understand what you are looking for,  you have the basics on how the code work,  you should be able to fit it into the logic you need

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you very much for your help and support Sir. I have learnt a lot from you today and I am very grateful for your time. Have a great day ahead :)

Comment: However you are resetting your game, did move to view is not being called,  just put that code in your reset function, and call reset in didmovetoview

Comment: I tried to do  didMoveToView(view!) and self.view?.presentScene(self)  - both separately and it is crashing and terminating the game. Any pointers on how to call didmovetoView to restart please?

Comment: you don't call didmovetoview, you have a separate function called reset, that resets everything you need reset, and you place the code that is in the didmovetoview into this reset function, then just call reset from withing didmovetoview

Comment: So gameOver() function of mine is a separate function. It is called from didBeginContact() when after certain collisions take place, the game freezes and game over text is presented. When the user taps now, touchesBegan() knows that gameOver() is live and it resets the score and removes all the children from the main nodes and hence the game starts again. This is my current loop.

As per your suggestion, if I call a reset function from didMoveToView then it will only call it once (when the game renders initally) right? That too if the conditions aren't met then it won't activate.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here, it is hard to think about your game in such a broad way when I do not know your logic.  But to keep it simple, just copy the code that is in the didmovetoview into your gameover function, and later on when you learn how to reduce duplicate code, you can go back and fix it

Comment: When I call a function from didMoveToView, it will only call it once right? However I want that function to be called when certain collisions take place. That is why  I call it from didBeginContact.

Comment: I don't need to understand what your logic is doing, we are deeply off the bounds of this answer,  didMoveToView only gets called when the scene moves to the view (Usually this is once), if you need the function to be called again, you need to manually state it that you want it to be called again.  If you need to call it again in didBeginContact, that is fine.  But you just need to make sure that your logic is correct.  I find it easier to design a game by writing out in your native tounge and step through it in your mind.  Once you have the language down, then attempt to translate it to swift

Comment: We are indeed beyond the original question Sir. I will research into self.view?.presentScene(self)  and how it can be used to reset. Thanks a lot for your time and patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107659/discussion-between-hasnain-and-knight0fdragon).

Answer (score 2):

Also an alternative to the `NSTimer` is to use `SKAction`s.

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where would I use this? Essentially  I want the function makeWalls to be called more frequently once score>=2

Comment: We are at a point in swifts programming life that people coming into it have no understanding of objective c, so to make your answers better I would mention you are writing them in objective c if the OP did not use objective c tags or said in the question objective c is acceptable as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you shouldn't be using `NSTimers` in `SpriteKit` at all.

Use `SKAction`:

```
    runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.4),
            SKAction.runBlock({
                self.makeWalls()
            })
        ])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for that hamobi. Do you mean create a new function called runAction? Where would I call it from then? Sorry I am new to SpriteKit. I want the function makeWalls to be called more frequently once the score >=2. Thanks.

Comment: you can assign actions like these right to your scene.  Inside of GameScene.swift, when you are ready to run the action (DO NOT RUN IN UPDATE) just call `self.runAction(....)`.  just note, you will need to actually remove actions when you are done with them if you end up using a repeatforever action, which hamobi does not discuss in his answer,

Comment: do a little research on SKAction its a pretty fundamental part of spritekit.  you can call runAction from a scene or any SKNode object

Comment: Hi,
So the logic is such that the makeWalls functions is called from the didMoveToView function. This (makeWalls) creates walls which are moved till the end of the screen once and only once. For me to repeat the creation of these walls, I created an NSTimer in didMoveToView (slowTimer) which calls makeWalls every 3 seconds. 

What I want is to amend this NSTimer (slowTimer) when the score is >2 such that makeWalls is now called every 1.4 seconds. From my research, this can't be done directly.  Hence not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because the spawning action is simple eg. wait + add walls, you could just modify the speed of the spawning action, like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var score = 0 { didSet{changeSpawningSpeed() } }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)
        let block = SKAction.runBlock({ [unowned self] in self.spawnWalls()})
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, block])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: "spawning")
    }

    func spawnWalls(){print("Walls spawned")}

    func changeSpawningSpeed(){

        if score == 2 {
            if let action = actionForKey("spawning"){action.speed += 1.0}
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        score += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if you want to increase the speed of action each time, you  can change the condition to `>= 2` ... It is up to you how and when you will increase the speed of spawning action.

Comment: I would have done speed in my version, but I am not sure of the person's math skills to figure out the math to apply to speed to make any time changes if they needed it to fire on intervals.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah, this can be done in a few ways and modifying the speed is just one of them... Initially I voted up your answer, because in general, that would be a workable solution. Run an action, and reset it when appropriate (also you could probably shorten it a bit and avoid code duplication). But I added this as another possible solution. Thanks for the upvote though (if it was you) :)

Comment: Yeah I upvoted because your answer is a viable answer,  I agree the code can be a lot shorter,  but from the code you could tell the OP is a novice,  and we were all at that state where more was easier to understand.  Nice touch on += 1 to make it swift 3 compliant

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Haha you've noticed the += thing. I can't imagine a programming language without ++ stuff ... But I am adapting slowly as you can see :)

Comment: I am not happy with the dropping of c  style coding support all together,  but we all need to adapt or perish.  It is just tough when bouncing from multiple c style languages,  but seems to be more and more easier for the python developers haha