# SKAction not restarting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

In my `didMoveToView` , I have the following code :

```
let spawnWall = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.makeWalls();});
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(2.9),spawnWall])
let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence);
self.runAction(repeatForever, withKey:"makeWalls");
```

Which basically calls the function `makeWalls` every 2.9 seconds.

Now whenever there is a touch, the `touchesBegan` function calls a function called `changeSpeed` which does this:

```
func changeSpeed()
{
    if score >= 2

    {
        self.removeActionForKey("makeWalls");
        makeWallsDividerT = 300;
        let spawnWall = SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.makeWalls();});
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.4),spawnWall])
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence);
        self.runAction(repeatForever, withKey:"makeWalls");
    }
}
```

Essentially stops the previous SKAction that was initiated from didMoveToView and calls makeWalls much faster (every 1.4 seconds), if and only if the score is >=2.

In my gameReset code, I have the following :

```
self.removeAllActions()
self.removeAllChildren()
self.view?.presentScene(self)
```

**I am expecting**

That when the game restarts, `makeWalls` is called every 2.9 seconds, till the score is >=2 and then call makeWalls every 1.4 seconds.

**What is happening**

`makeWalls` is being called every 1.4 seconds when it is meant to do the above. I say so because the walls appear to come faster.

**What I also tried and didn't work**

I tried putting in  `self.removeActionForKey("makeWalls");` in the `didMoveToView` code that I pasted above in the fist block of code. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work either.

**Class**

Can be found here:
https://paste.ee/p/tGlrY#AtdTJLRBGUcPFXtkVo2XEvsFJkNK1hLR

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: you never reset the score

Comment: Oh yea! I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't help. It is still resetting to the faster call of makeWalls of every 1.4 seconds.

Comment: you need to post the entire class, you are doing something wrong

Comment: Hi,
Apologies for the late reply as I was away. Kindly find it here:

https://paste.ee/p/GoazO#lKZ6ye9mVocnzqIz0a5JwZEfwPCoVQrl

Comment: your code doesn't even work, make walls does nothing your game over does nothing, I have no idea what is going on here, at no point are you creating a new scene, so it won't go to 2.9

Comment: Basically it just has walls coming from the top. Everything happens in the same scene and hence there are no other classes in the game.

Comment: you have no reset code and your make walls is empty

Comment: In didBeginContact, when there is a collision between the main character and avoid, these are applied:

freezeMainChar = 1
movingObjects.speed = 0
                
and displayGameOver() is triggered. Now when the user taps the screen this time, in touchesBegan, it goes into the 'else'. This is where the reset happens. Thanks.

Comment: no that doesn't work because you set freezemainchar to 1, but your didbegintouch filters out only 0,  you never reset it back to 0

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally had deleted the bracket. Updated it here:
https://paste.ee/p/TwGNO#KR8wzmuSihllbbvqA5wpCTwPtA71hFcr

So in the 'else' of the touchesBegan, freezeMainChar is reset to 0. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
I just added a link to the most recent code. Thanks.

Comment: That link only stays open for a few days it looks like

Comment: I just added a fresh link :
https://paste.ee/p/UyXK3#MQlp4Zw0dgRniG0tgr9fH1SFDmKUVQi8

Comment: there is no way this code is going back to the faster speed

Comment: now your background moving is a different story, you do not reset the background speed

Comment: yikes,  you add the background speed 3 times per game, then on reset you  add it 6 times,  You should look into fixing it

Comment: I do that in lines 181 and 182 : 
movingObjects.removeAllChildren()
movingObjects.removeAllActions()

Comment: you make background twice

Comment: combine your else and your didmovetoview, into your didmovetoview code, and only present the new scene in your else

Comment: If I cut the else of the touchesBegan into didMoveToView then the game won't run till certain conditions are met right? As in it will just reset the code to 0 at the end automaticaly (as that is what the else statement has in it).

I removed   makeBackground () from the else of touchesBegan. Still doesn't work unfortunately. Sorry for the trouble as I learnt this from a tutorial from udemy and really struggling. Thanks!

Comment: then leave the reset code, just remove all the duplicate code between the two

Comment: I have this left in the else of the touchesBegan. Unfortunately it still doesn't work as expected:


            score = 0
            scoreLabel.text = "0"

            movingObjects.removeAllChildren()
            movingObjects.removeAllActions()
            gameOverLabelHolder.removeAllChildren()
          
            freezeMainChar = 0
            movingObjects.speed = 1
           
            self.removeAllActions()
            self.removeAllChildren()
            
            //didMoveToView(view!)
        
           
            
            self.view?.presentScene(self)

Comment: Abandon this and start over, there is no helping you

Comment: I am very sorry for being annoying. Could you kindly give it one more shot please Sir? I would really, highly appreciate it. We are very close and I've been stuck on this for a very long time, from the time I had those NSTimers on this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265482/multiple-nstimers-in-spritekit-not-working-as-expected

Thanks for your help as I am very stuck.

Comment: Im not saying this to be aggravating,  the issue is unknown. Start over with what you now know

Comment: Sure, before we close it Sir, do you mind having one last look please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your question with any new info that was created from this back and forth. I took a peak at what I believe is the most recent code you are trying to troubleshoot and the only odd thing I really see is that instead of creating a new scene you are representing the scene which I find a bit odd.

Comment: Also are you having this issue every time you present the scene or just after the first time you present the scene?

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/tGlrY#AtdTJLRBGUcPFXtkVo2XEvsFJkNK1hLR is the most recent code now @SkylerLauren . The first time the game runs, it works as expected. However once the score is >=2 and then when it is game over, upon reset, the makeWalls is then called every 1.4 seconds from the beginning. As in it is meant to call it every 2.9 seconds first till the score is >=2 and then every 1.4 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. If it doesn't solve your problem I highly recommend updating your question with this link and any additional info that could help others find a solution to help you. =)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Sir, I would like to seriously thank you from the bottom of my heart for your patience, support and your guidance throughout this session. I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your biggest issue is the scene isn't resetting itself properly. I have yet to see someone do what you are doing and re presenting your scene (or call didMoveToView directly which I don't think is ever suppose to be called directly) instead of re initing a new scene. I would give the following a try...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    if freezeMainChar == 0
    {
        changeSpeed()
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch?.locationInNode(self)

        if touchLocation!.x == 450
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    else
    {
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "0"

        movingObjects.removeAllChildren()
        movingObjects.removeAllActions()
        gameOverLabelHolder.removeAllChildren()

        freezeMainChar = 0
        movingObjects.speed = 1

        self.removeAllActions()
        self.removeAllChildren()

        //didMoveToView(view!)
        let newScene = GameScene(size: size)
        newScene.scaleMode = scene.scaleMode
        view.presentScene(newScene)
    }

}
```

This should start everything fresh for a new game. Hopefully that helps solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that Sir. For this line:
  SKView.presentScene(newScene) , I get the compilation error : ambiguous reference to member 'presentScene'

Comment: YES!!!! I am gonna cry! Finally it works!!! Thank you very much for your help :) 

Could you kindly explain (if you don't mind) what is happening please? I understand that you're creating a new scene and making it the same scale as the current scene and then presenting it. Shouldn't this new scene just be empty as we didn't assign anything to it (apart from the scale)? And how does it do the same thing as restarting didMoveToView ? 

Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: @Hasnain Look at this as same as when you are presenting your scene for the first time (from view controller). Immediately after the new scene is presented by the view (`SKView`), a `didMoveToView` method (from that scene) is called automatically. This is the moment where scene's content is created usually. You are not supposed to call `didMoveToView` manually though. So, presented scene is not empty when you present it for the first time. Do you agree? Same goes when you are presenting a new scene at any other moment in your game. The only difference is that you are replacing current scene.

Comment: @Hasnain Of course, if you are not adding any content inside scene's init or scene's `didMoveToView`, then scene will not have any content when presented by the view. But this is not the case with your example, because you are adding the content into scene's `didMoveToView` already.

Comment: @Hasnain sorry I got busy and couldn't answer but it appears Whirlwind explained why it works. If this resolved your issues please don't forget to accept and best of luck with your game.

Comment: Thank you very much @Whirlwind. Skyler Lauren I really appreciate your help. Thanks for going through my code and pointing this out. Hope you have a great day Sir. Kind Regards.

Comment: You are welcome. It would be nice of you to award that bounty to Skyler. After all, that is what you should do when if you are satisfied with someone's answer and it solves your problem . Which is not a must of course, and you can keep the bounty opened until it ends :) if you are hoping for more answers.

Comment: Thanks @Whirlwind. I wanted to do so straight away, however it said that I had to wait for 8 hours to do so. Cheers and have a great day :)